# How do I make a div fixed?

Tags: html, position, fixed

I want to make a donation box as a div, but I want it to move with the page as you scroll without changing its position or staying in its old place (i.e. position: fixed). I gave the div positioning yet it wont move for some reason, it just gets pushed away when a page gets longer.

```
<head>
<style>
#donationbutton {
color: blue;
background-color:  yellow;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100px;
padding:10px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 25px;
position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="something" style="text-decoration: none;">
<div id="donationbutton">
    DONATE
</div>
</a>
</body>
```

`

Comment: You mentioned the use of `position:fixed`, yet I don't see it in your code. Why not?

Comment: Could you represent your problem in a http://jsfiddle.com/, please? (to be easier to understand). I don't see anything wrong except that you are talking about `position:fixed` but in your code it is `relative`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `position: fixed` instead of `position: relative` if you want it to stay in place

```
#donationbutton {
   color: blue;
   background-color:  yellow;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 100px;
   padding:10px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-radius: 25px;
   position: fixed; <--------- 
}
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjkoLtgp/)

Just understand that `position: fixed` removes the element from the flow of the document so it won't behave like a normal block element

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed
```

is what youre looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/69/